# Имеется ли связь между словами толк и толчок?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

"Толк" с семантикой - резон, смысл. Толчок - тычок.  Есть же выражение: "я тебе толкую", то есть объясняю, и есть - "втолковываю",  тоже объясняю, только с бОльшим усердием,  - вталкиваю свою мысль.
 Также интересно и происхождение данных лексем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если обратиться к этимологическим словарям, то легко убедиться, что *толк* и *толкать* восходят к разным основам.

И действительно, почему бы им быть однокоренными? Не рассматривая лингвистические причины, можно натолкнуться на чисто семантические трудности в объяснении связи обсуждаемых слов. «Вталкивание мысли», это, конечно, хорошо, но как объяснить, что *толк* 'разговор' и производный от него глагол *толковать* 'говорить' связаны с *толкать* 'перемещать в пространстве'?

Исходное значение первых двух связано именно с речевой деятельностью, и этот факт подтверждается параллелями (когнатами) в других индоевропейских языках. Поэтому объяснять *толк* через *толкать* бессмысленно. Впрочем, обратная операция тоже неправдоподобна: *толочь* и проч. имеют вполне надежных однокоренных индоевропейских родственников со значением физического действия с применением грубой силы. Иначе говоря, нельзя объяснять связь этих слов на уровне современного языка (если вообще эту связь можно объяснять на каком угодно уровне).

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, это **разные** слова.

По Шанскому, ТОЛК -исходное тълкъ - от **толковать,** родств. др.-инд. tarkas «предположение», лат. Loqu
i «говорить, называть», изменилось в **толк** после падения редуцированных.

https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%82/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA

У Фасмера то же самое:

> толк - толкова́ть, -у́ю, укр. толк, толкува́ти, др.-русск. тълкъ
>   «толкование», «толмач, переводчик», ст.-слав. тлъкъ ἑρμηνεύς (Супр.),
>   цслав. тлъковати, болг. тълку́вам (Младенов 644).

Толчок - от ТОЛКАТЬ.

> Суффиксальное образование от той же основы (с перегласовкой ь/е), что
>   толочь. Исходное *tьlkati > толкать после отвердения плавного л,
>   изменения ь в ъ и последующего прояснения ъ в о в результате падения
>   редуцированных и отпадения конечного...

https://shansky.lexicography.online/%D1%82/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Звучание близко - что ты  мне толкуешь - втолковываешь похоже на толкаешь, тем более, что в просторечии они сближаются: **"речь толкал"**, но ведь здесь имеется в виду **толковал**, а не **толкал**.

Comment: Людмила, о каком «древнем корне» *tъ вы ведете речь?

Comment: Это я, наверно, про первообраз начиталась, на другом ресурсе пытались вместе Библию толковать, залезли в церковно-славянский, там один товарищ утверждает, что в праиндоевропейском текст -ткать - течь - текти с одним древним корнем   *tъ, а k-суфф. и предположил, что в древнерусском  тълкъ =  тъ + лкъ. Пыталась восстановить ссылку - не нашла почему-то. Впрочем, может, это так называемая "наивная этимология". С праиндоевропейским у нас напряг.

Comment: Выглядит все это крайне сомнительно, так что я бы подумал дважды, прежде чем публиковать.

Comment: Сейчас уберу лишнее.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Ответ:**

**В словаре Черных**  есть отдельные статьи (1) для слов ***толкать/толкнуть, толочь, ткнуть*** (физические действия) и  (2) для слова ***толк*** (и.-е. корень tolk  – говорить, излагать).  Между собой он их явно не связывает.

**Из современного словаря:**

**ТОЛК,**  м. 1. Разг. Смысл, разумное содержание чего-л. 2. Разг. Прок, польза. 3. обычно мн.: толки,  Разговоры, пересуды.

**ТОЛКОВАТЬ,** 1. что. Определять смысл, значение чего-л., понимать и объяснять что-л. каким-л. образом; истолковывать.2. (что). Разг. Объяснять кому-л. что-л., помогая усвоить, понять; растолковывать.

Как мы видим, ***толковать*** – это не просто говорить что-то, а определять смысл чего-либо  и интерпретировать (объяснять) его (а толк – смысл или польза). **Но каким образом речевой глагол *толковать*  связан со смыслом и пользой – вот в чем  вопрос.**

**2) Приложение к ответу (материал для размышления)**

В Интернете есть разные статьи о слове ***толк***. Сложно поручиться за их достоверность (это каждый должен решать для себя), но определенный интерес к проблеме они вызывают, например:

1. [http://forum-eurasica.ru/index.php?/topic/1284-слово-толмач/](http://forum-eurasica.ru/index.php?/topic/1284-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87/)

Есть похожие по звучанию и смыслу слова у индоевропейцев – TALK, TELL, ТОЛК. Современные версии таковы:

Русское ТОЛМАЧ – заимствование из тюркского . В русском ему родственно (соответствует?) слово ЯЗЫК, в английском TONGUE, в латинском LINGVO.

Английские TALK, TELL не связаны с упомянутыми выше словами, а родственны слову TALE с первозначением **СЧЕТ, ЧИСЛО**.

Русское слово ТОЛК не связано с вышеприведенными словами и происходит **от индоевропейского корня со значением ИНТЕРПРЕТИРОВАТЬ.**

2. https://otvet.mail.ru/question/67598589

**Что предлагают словари?** Они связывают русский "толк" с толкованием, и далее, с толмачом. Начинают приводить примеры из балтийских (tùlkas "толмач, переводчик", лтш. tul̃ks, эст. tulk, ср. -нж. -нем. tolk, др. -сканд. tulkr – то же, нидерл. tolk). И "логично" выводят нас на германский источник. Что слово "толк" якобы заимствовано из германских.

Смотрим слово talk, которое само, оказывается производное от tale, **прагерманского *talo, язык, речь.**

Тут ещё по ходу вспоминаем, что на всех без исключения **тюркских** язык будет "тил/дил" с вариантами ...  Так вот, возвращаясь к прагерманской форме. Сама форма *talo восходит к праинд. основе *del, "считать", "рассчитывать" (так в словарях) . (Кстати,  у англ. слова ***tale*** действительно есть значение ***счёт*** https://wooordhunt.ru/word/tale)

Так что же такое, это *del? **Это русское слово "дело"**. Толк, как и сами talk/tale/tell восходят к основе del, **древнейшее значение** которого лучше, чем в русском не просматривается.

Хотя приведенное объяснение "толк – это дело/полезное деятельность" не вызывают большого доверия (это всё-таки не статьи из общеизвестных авторитетных словарей), **но какое-то объяснение должно быть.**

У Черных: и.-е. корень глагола ***делать*** – dhe, в о.-с основе слова ***дело*** выделяется суффикс l. Больше никаких сведений нет, про праинд. основу **del** (***считать, рассчитывать***, а уже тем более ***делать***, то есть заниматься полезной деятельностью)  ничего не сказано.

**Вот такие сложные связи** просматриваются у русского слова ***толковать*** с другими языками: просто речевая деятельность (англ. talk), или нахождение толка (смысла, пользы, расчета) в какой-либо деятельности, или даже сама полезная деятельность (дело).