# Существует ли этимологическая связь между русским словом «толк» и английским словом «talk»?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Внешняя схожесть русского слова «толк» и английского слова «talk» наводит на размышления об их общем происхождении.

У слова «толк» есть значения (Согласно словарю русского языка в 4 томах РАН Евгеньевой):

> Устар. Объяснение, толкование чему-л. *[Лиза:] Нельзя ни встать, ни
> сесть, ни выйти, ни войти; Всему вы толк иной умеете найти.* Грибоедов,
> Притворная неверность. *[Лизанька:] Вы напрасно сердитесь и даете не
> такой толк моим словам.* Белинский, Пятидесятилетний дядюшка.

и

> *обычно мн. ч. (то́лки, -ов).* Разговоры, пересуды. Целый день только и толку было, что о Семене Ивановиче. Достоевский, Господин Прохарчин.
> *Рассказ вызвал много шумных и разнообразных толков.* Куприн, Святая
> любовь.

Согласно этимологическому словарю Шанского:

> Толк. Искон. Исходное тълкъ, родств. др.-инд. tarkas «предположение»,
> лат. loqui «говорить, называть», изменилось в толк после падения
> редуцированных.

Как по значению, так и этимологически слово связно с говорением.

Согласно [Викисловарю](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/talk) этимология «talk»:

> From Middle English talken, talkien, from Old English tealcian (“to
> talk, chat”), from Proto-Germanic *talkōną (“to talk, chatter”),
> frequentative form of Proto-Germanic *talōną (“to count, recount,
> tell”), from Proto-Indo-European *dol-, *del- (“to aim, calculate,
> adjust, count”), equivalent to tell +‎ -k. Cognate with Scots talk
> (“to talk”), Low German taalken (“to talk”). Related also to Danish
> tale (“to talk, speak”), Swedish tala (“to talk, speak, say,
> chatter”), Icelandic tala (“to talk”), Old English talian (“to count,
> calculate, reckon, account, consider, think, esteem, value; argue;
> tell, relate; impute, assign”). More at tale.

Хотя есть похожие слова в разных языках, точного соотвествия не видно.

Существует ли этимологическая связь между русским словом «толк» и английским словом «talk» или это просто внешнее совпадение?

Comment: Здесь кое-что дополнительно можно почитать еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447860/Имеется-ли-связь-между-словами-толк-и-толчок

Comment: @tum_ Спасибо за помощь.